problema al imprimir pdf con python pywin2
Hola tengo problemas al imprimir con python, me muestra el siguiente error
pywintypes error (31, 'shellexecute', 'uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. ')
¿Alguien tiene una sugerencia?
Este es el código
output_path=r"C:\Users\victo\desktop\hola.pdf"      
default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", output_path, '/d:{}'.format(default_printer), ".", 0)


No he trabajado con el módulo, pero según esta pregunta, una causa del error es porque no hay un lector de PDF instalado en el equipo.

Hola, tengo instalado acrobat,edge que tambien funciona como lector de PDF y PDF creator

Hola si había relación con el lector de PDF instalado

Funciono el siguiente código asociando los archivos PDF con Acrobat ya que previamente estaban asociados con Edge
import win32api
import os
import win32print
output_path=r"C:\Users\victo\desktop\acuerdo1.pdf"      
default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", output_path, '/d:{}'.format(default_printer), ".", 0)

